# .gitignore - ignore file starting with ~

Tags: regex, git, gitignore

To ignore any file starting with ~(tilde), I put following in gitignore file

```
^~.*
```

But, it is not working for the file name starting with ~(eg. ~$ofession email.docx).

There is no issue with gitignore configuration setting as other patterns are working well.

What is wrong here with the regular expression?

Comment: `gitignore` doesn't support regular expressions afaik, but has glob format. Could you try removing `^` from the beginning of the line? yes, and the any remaining regexp logic...

Comment: @zatta thank you for your great information. yes, it worked well after removing ^ and .(dot)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regular expressions are not supported in `.gitignore`, you can use globs only. To fix it, use `~*`, that will ignore anything starts with tilde.

Answer (score 16):

You may escape a character by surrounding it with "[]":

```
[~][$]*
```

This will ignore any Microsoft temporary/backup files.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

^~.* is ignoring only files that *only* begin with ~.  e.g. "~.txt" or "~.docx".

Change it to ^~*

Comment: sorry it didn't work. as @zatta said regexp are not supported in .gitignore